# How can I read all parquet files in an Azure Storage Container into an Azure Machine Learning Studio Workspace without specifying file names?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have an Azure storage container with 20 parquet files and I want to read them into an Azure Machine Learning Studio Workspace. I can connect to my container with an https based path and can read a single file at a time by specifying the file name itself. This works fine on a small scale but once I scale up to hundreds of files the situation becomes untenable. I would like a method that will just read all the files in the storage container one by one without needing to give it the actual file names.

I have found methods of doing this where you are connecting your local machine to cloud storage but I have not found anything that works with a cloud compute instance in an Azure Machine Learning Studio work space. I have tried dumping the files into my filesystem on the cloud workspace and reading "locally" which does work. However, I would like a method that can directly read from Azure storage containers. I have found older methods that involve the Execute Python Script module but they are all nearly 8 years old so I would like to know if better methods exist.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a **Data Store** followed by **Data Asset** in Machine Learning Studio which points to the folder having all the parquet files
2. You will be able to access all these files both programmatically and using UI
3. If you want to access it programmatically, you can refer the below documentation:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.dataset_factory.tabulardatasetfactory?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-data-dataset-factory-tabulardatasetfactory-from-delimited-files

Find more about datastore and data asset up here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-data